# run batch script as function in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, batch-file

I have written a few simple batch scripts for Windows

I am now working on creating a VB Form application

I would like to be able to create some function in VB that has the code of my batch script (in Batch file syntax)
and then be able to call and run that code in my VB program

I could have my batch scripts somewhere on disk and then call them with the "shell" function but I do not want to have the batch scripts be actual files

Is there a way to do this? or will I have to write my Batch script in VB syntax and use the shell function

Comment: They have no way to execute without being in a batch file on disk. If you want to avoid having disk files, you'll have to write the same functionality in VB yourself without the batch script language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, you have a few options:

1. have the batch files on the PC and you call it via process.start
2. the text of the batch file is embedded in your application which in turn creates files and runs then via process.start
3. rewrite your batch into vb.net and lose the command console scripts
4. write your own converter that processes batch file script and runs the appropriate vb.net code to emulate the .bat/.cmd file scripts.
5. you can call "cmd.exe /c" and provide a string; this may be what you are specifically needing.

I'd personally prefer option 3 because it allows much simpler debugging/error handling.

**edit**
Option 5 added

Comment: Is there a way I can embed the batch file in my program and run it from inside the program

So I don't have to have the batch files as external files

Comment: I ended up going with option 2 and used the:
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText method

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Process class to run it.

```
Process.Start({batch file})
```